# Convolution of Gaussian and Lorentzian functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, distributions, convolution

I have a Gaussian and a Lorentzian function here;

```
gd[v_] = Sqrt[(4*Log[2]/Pi)]*(1/Dw)*Exp[-4*Log[2]*((v - v0)/Dw)^2]
gl[v_] = (Lw/2/Pi)/((v - v0)^2 + (Lw/2)^2);
```

I want to get a Voigt function by using the convolution of the above two functions,

```
Voi[v_] = Integrate[gd[v']*gl[v' - v], {v', -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

but it just returns the input,

So, how to do this convolution in Mathematica?

Comment: Why don't you use VoigtDistribution[ lorentzwidth, gaussianwidth ], which is a built-in function? This convolution has not an analytical formula, and it is difficult to evaluate numerically. It is pretty much studied, since it appears in several contexts, in particular in astrophysics and x-ray spectroscopy.

Answer (score 7):

It seems, that MMA can't do that integral analytically (working with Version 8.0). Also `Convolve`didn't do the job.

Do it numerically. By the way, don't use `v'`, because it is interpreted as Derivative and regard, the correct definition is `gl[v - vs, v0, Lw]`, not `vs-v`.

```
gd[v_, v0_, Dw_] = 
   Sqrt[(4*Log[2]/Pi)]*(1/Dw)*Exp[-4*Log[2]*((v - v0)/Dw)^2];

gl[v_, v0_, Lw_] = (Lw/2/Pi)/((v - v0)^2 + (Lw/2)^2);

Voi[v_, v0_, Dw_, Lw_] := 
    NIntegrate[gd[vs, v0, Dw]*gl[v - vs, v0, Lw], {vs, -Infinity, Infinity}]

Plot[{gd[v, 1, 2], gl[v, 1, 1/2], Voi[v, 1, 2, 1/2]}, {v, -5, 5}, 
   PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Green, Blue, Red}]
```

[image]